# How to display text based on the column value from database?

Tags: asp.net

i am using template field to display text based on condition in table field.

i have field name Qualification i used to store integer value such as 4 or 3
if it is 4 then display "Post Graduate" else "Graduate" in gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetQual(int)(Eval("Qualification")) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

public static string GetQual(int value)
    {
        if (value == 4)
        {
            return "Post Graduate";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Graduate";

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `RowDataBound` since it's more readable and maintainable:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;  // dependas on the DataSource, maybe you need to use the debugger to see what it is
        int qualification = row.Field<int>("Qualification");
        Label lblQuali = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
        lblQuali.Text = qualification == 4 ? "Post Graduate" : "Graduate";
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to pass the column value to GetQual function but am getting error. How to pass the value to the fucntion?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `GetQual` function to take a string instead of an int.  You can then parse the string inside the `GetQual` function and handle accordingly.  The `Eval()` will always return a string.