# How to put HTML in a Gridview Cell

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to put HTML in a gridview cell for example:

```
<span class="badge badge-info">Processing</span>
```

It makes the Processing Text highlight blue, and I am trying to change the color to green depending on a value.  How would I do this?  I know using a Literal could work, but I do not know how to do that inside a Gridview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539151/how-to-display-text-based-on-the-column-value-from-database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048762/change-gridview-row-color-based-on-condition-in-c-sharp

Comment: That is C# and I am trying to pass HTML through

Comment: how are you populating the grid? back end code? if so, handle the events shown in the samples. regardless of language, the technique is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it`s some how ambiguous to know what you want
but hope this will help

```
int place=0; //the cell to add the literal in
foreach (GridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{           
    if (value)
    row.Cells[place].Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class=\"toto\"> blah</span>"));
}
```